# SUM on multiple separate columns in LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, linq, sum

Does anyone know how to sum multiple columns properly and efficiently.

I have a massive Join Query

```
db.myTable.Join(...)
.Join(...)
.Join(...)
.Join(...)
.Join(...)
.Join(...)
.Where(...)
```

What I need to now do, is **sum Column A, B, C and D. And Count E.**

So i have one record with the sums in.

I tried using group by, and `Select(x => new myClass{A => x.})`

The below is **MAJORLY** inefficient

```
myClass mine = new myClass{ 
            Number = myList.GroupBy(x => x.u.ID).Count(),
            Area = myList.Sum(a => a.u.Area ?? 0),
            Rent = myList.Sum(a => a.r.Rent ?? 0)   ,
            ERV = myList.Sum(a => a.e.ERV ?? 0)
        };
```

The below is Efficient but only sums the first grouping...

```
      myClass mine = (from p in myList
                            group p by p.u.ID into g
                            select  new myClass
                            { 
                                Number = g.Count(),
                            Area = g.Sum(a => a.u.Area ?? 0),
                            Rent = g.Sum(a => a.r.Rent ?? 0)   ,
                            ERV = g.Sum(a => a.e.ERV ?? 0)
        }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: What do you mean by second query `only sums the first grouping`?

Comment: @Kaf I want the sum of All the rents, aka not grouped. But i need the count of the unique IDs (not a unique key). The second query Groups by u.ID, Sums up the values within each group, and then only returns the first group. (`FirstOrDefault`) - Not sure how to sum the groups, or if im doing it wrong.

Comment: Second query returns first group because of `.FirstOrDefault()`.

Comment: I dont want a list of Summaries for each grouping. I want a single Summary of the entire thing.

Comment: Then why do you group by `p.u.ID`?

Comment: @Kaf no idea. is there a better way to count distinct IDs in this scenario. And how would I Group and sum the entire thing. I cannot apply `Sum` in `Select` or `Single`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to get the `Distinct Count()` of *Number field* with *ungrouped* `Sum()` of other fields in a single record.

```
var mine = (from x in (from p in mc 
                       group p by p.u.id into g1
                       select new { 
                             Number = g1.Count(),
                             Area = g1.Sum(a => a.u.Area??0),
                             Rent = g1.Sum(a => a.u.Rent??0),
                             ERV = g1.Sum(a => a.e.ERV ?? 0)
                       })
                    group x by 1 into g2
                    select new myClass {
                             Number = g2.Count(),
                             Area = g2.Sum(a => a.Area),
                             Rent = g2.Sum(a => a.Rent),
                             ERV = g2.Sum(a => a.ERV)
                    }).FirstOrDefault();
```